# Trying to DELETE from INNER JOIN (MYSQL via PHP) WHERE the joined table has the value I want to key off?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MYSQL:

```
Encounters  
+----+--------+------------+
| Id | GameId | LocationId |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | 5      |     10     |
| 2  | 5      |     12     |
| 3  | 5      |     45     |
+----+--------+------------+
EncounterCards  
+----+-------------+--------+
| Id | EncounterId | CardId |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  6 | 1           | 26     |
|  7 | 2           |  5     |
|  8 | 3           |  5     |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

I'm trying to join the two tables and delete all of the records in the `EncounterCards` table where the `GameId = 5`. When I do an inner join, it doesn't seem to let me do this because it's looking for the `GameId` column in the `EncounterCards` table, but it's only in the Encounters table.

So in this use case, it would delete ALL records from the `EncounterCards` table.

Here is my query:

```
`$query = "DELETE FROM EncounterCards INNER JOIN Encounters ON Encounters.Id = EncounterCards.EncounterId WHERE Encounters.GameId = {$game_id}";`
```

Comment: For formatting help, click the big fat orange question mark on the right side of the formatting toolbar.  You don't need to mangle your post with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using an `INNER JOIN` is *not* that important in your case you could also use the following:

```
DELETE FROM EncounterCards
WHERE EncounterId IN (
    SELECT id FROM Encounters
    WHERE GameId = {game_id_to_filter}
);
```

Comment: BAM. That was easier than Inner Join. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
DELETE EncounterCards 
FROM EncounterCards INNER JOIN Encounters 
ON Encounters.Id = EncounterCards.EncounterId 
WHERE Encounters.GameId = {$game_id}
```

Table name was added before the FROM keyword. Refer to the [Multiple-Table DELETE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify where the records should be deleted. In this case, i have added an `ALIAS` before the `FROM` keyword.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    EncounterCards a 
        INNER JOIN Encounters b
            ON a.EncounterID = b.ID
WHERE   b.GameID = 5
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20c56/1)